# How do I go about getting Non Owners Auto Insurance in NJ

Tags: united-states, car-insurance, new-jersey

I'm currently in the `US` as a non immigrant worker and a resident of `Jersey City, NJ`. I've recently got a NJ drivers license, I don't own a vehicle and been renting cars over the weekends to see places.

My Credit Cards cover the Collision Damage but I'm stuck with the state mandated minimum liability coverage. I don't have significant assets here and I feel a bit vulnerable having only the minimum liability coverage.

I read about `Non-Owner Insurance` online and it seemed like a good option to me but am finding it very hard to get a quote online and when I call companies, they either don't offer it in NJ or the premiums are insanely expensive.

Here are my findings -

- Geico - $800 for 6 months offer the State Minimum at this rate.
- State Farm - Contacted agent $1100 for 6 months for 100/300/100
- Progressive - Doesn't write this Policy in NJ
- Esurance - Doesn't write this policy in NJ
- [Mark Lauria, found online agents](http://www.marklauria.com/content/personal/auto/coverage/rental-car) - Wanted SSN over phone, had to say no

My question(s) are -

- Does it make sense for me to get Non owners insurance? (My net worth is about $30K and I make about $100K an year)
- What's a competitive rate for such policies? (I'm only interested in liability insurance, What would I get for $30/month. I would ideally want a 100/300/100 policy)
- How do I go about finding these policies?
- Given how expensive these policies seem to be, does it make sense for me to buy a junker for a couple of hundred dollars and get liability on that?

If anyone has recommendations for an Agent or Insurance company that would fit my bill, that's super helpful.

Comment: Have you looked into a personal umbrella policy?

Comment: Related: [Where to get liability insurance for car rentals, as an add-on to Visa Collision Damage Waiver?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/37287/10997)

Comment: Companies will only sell you an Umbrella policy if you already have an existing policy(Renters/House owners) with them. Unfortunately I don't have either.

Answer (score 1):

Car rental companies will offer to sell you short-term insurance (pai, cdw, etc.). Expensive per day, may not be unreasonable if you don't have other coverage